# Dividing by four in combobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm a new programmer doing a date of birth selector for part of my project. I have got everything set up apart from a few things and I am unsure of how to do these things.

```
ArrayList<String> years_tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        years_tmp.add("Year");
        for(int years = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) ; years>=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-90;years--)
        {
            years_tmp.add(years+"");
        }


        Y = new JComboBox(years_tmp.toArray());
```

Above is my part of my code for a JComboBox which lists the previous 90 years and has the word "Years" as the first object.

For my code above how would I list the years like it currently does, but to only display years which divide by four exactly (leap years)?

Also how do I make it so once the JComboBox list has been opened the selection years can not be selected so when the value is saved in my save file it does not allow the save of the word "Years"?

Comment: `if (years % 4 == 0) {years_tmp.add(years+"");}`. Although, that's not _exactly_ the leap year rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value which can be devided be 4 without a rest you can use the modulo operator '%':

```
if(year % 4 == 0) {
    ...
}
```

To disallow the Selection of "year" itself, you have several ways. One could be to append an ItemListener to your ComboBox and check whether the user selected the "year" value. If the user selected this value you can print an error message or just select another value - maybe the next possible one. You also can do more fancy stuff like disabling the save Button if the user selected an invalid value..

I think this should help you to get to the right direction.